Nodejs Websocket Connect by wss
We hired a vps with Ubuntu and installed nodejs for a chat server, and it will be consumed by external websocket connections from other domains outside this vps. Let's encrypt certificate installed by CloudPanel on the domain.
Connections made via websocket to other domains and localhost work perfectly when connected via ws:// , but when we switch to wss:// it does not connect at all. We believe there is a problem with the SSL certificate usage configuration. But we didn't find anything, no firewall rules.
nodejs
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = 8081;
 
const serverOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/example.net.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/example.net.crt')
};

const serverData = https.createServer(serverOptions, app);

// Middleware CORS
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost', 'https://exampleexternal.net']
}));

const server = new WebSocket.Server({ serverData, noServer: true });

My .conf
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/example.net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/example.net.key;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
  server_name www.mysite.com;
  return 301 https://example.net$request_uri;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/example.net.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl-certificates/example.net.key;
    
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    
  server_name mysite.com www1.example.net;
  {{root}}

  {{nginx_access_log}}
  {{nginx_error_log}}

  if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$uri permanent;
  }

  location ~ /.well-known {
    auth_basic off;
    allow all;
  }

  {{settings}}

  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:{{app_port}}/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_connect_timeout 900;
    proxy_send_timeout 900;
    proxy_read_timeout 900;
    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
  }
}

client js
  let ws;
  ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.net:8081');

